# CONTAINS in Oracle 11.2

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-text

Is it possible to use something working like `CONTAINS` function from new Oracle?
I have 11.2 and would like to do sth like this:

```
select * from cars
inner join customers on customers.as_id = cars.as_id
where cars.type like 'AUDI' and contains(request, customers.name, 1) > 0;
```

so as I know I can't use `LIKE` here because `customers.name` is not a fixed value.
Is there a way to find some workaround for old Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LIKE` as follows:

```
select * 
  from cars
 inner join customers on customers.as_id = cars.as_id
 where cars.type = 'AUDI' -- You can use = here
   and request like '%' || customers.name || '%';
```

**Note:** `contains` clause is used for finding specific strings within an Oracle Text index. it can not be applied on normal columns.

Comment: "it can not be applied on normal columns." Yes it can, just create the index on the column and then you can use it; there is nothing non-"normal" about the column.

Answer (score 1):

`CONTAINS` is an Oracle text function; Oracle Text is supported on Oracle 11g.

Just create an Oracle text context index on the column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cars ( as_id, type, request ) AS
SELECT 1, 'AUDI', 'Requested by alice abbots on 2020-01-07' FROM DUAL;

CREATE INDEX cars__request__textidx ON cars(request) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;

CREATE TABLE customers ( as_id, name ) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice Abbots' FROM DUAL;
```

Then your query:

```sql
select * from cars
inner join customers on customers.as_id = cars.as_id
where cars.type like 'AUDI' and contains(request, customers.name, 1) > 0;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> AS_ID | TYPE | REQUEST                                 | AS_ID | NAME        
> ----: | :--- | :-------------------------------------- | ----: | :-----------
>     1 | AUDI | Requested by alice abbots on 2020-01-07 |     1 | Alice Abbots
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8d9e58ee66817c9fc9f0f889d733b7da)*